# Flexible, rounded corner box, with shadow, using images

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners, dropshadow

I have this white box that needs to be flexible vertically:

[image: rounded white box]

The fancy rounded corners and drop shadow are essencial:

[image: fancy details]

And the content of the box has to reach the edge of the white all around:

[image]

The problem is, I have very strict restrictions.

- I have to use images, no css3 for me. (client request, I know...)
- The background on which the box will be can change color, so ideally we work with transparency in those images.
- The background of the box itself will stay white.
- Browser support is reasonable, so negative margins, z-index tricks are fair game.
- **Ideally**, I want to stay away from hacks, .htc scripts and JavaScript influence.

You can tell me if I'm screwed on those restrictions, I don't mind. I would appreciate telling me why though.: )

Answer (score 1):

You need to chop the box into 3 sections. Top, middle and bottom.  Then you stretch the middle section to fill the variable sized area.  Look up the CSS Sliding door technique.

Comment: He's right.  Make your top and bottom sections only big enough to cover the drop shadow and 1 pixel of the white background.  Your middle part should include the left and right hand sides of the drop shadow and one pixel of the white background.  So, your graphics will be very wide, but only a few pixels high (depending on how big your drop shadows are).  Easiest way to implement in code I can think of is to use divs with these three images as the background (your middle div will repeat-y).

Comment: If I include de corners in my 3 images, like in the second pictures, and fill the middle section, I'll have a slight padding at the top and bottom. My content has to reach the entire white space inside.

Comment: here is a [random link to a howto](http://meekostuff.net/blog/CSS-Sliding-Doors/). At the bottom it disucsses some of the ways you can resolve the issue.

Comment: make sure you reset your margins and padding to zero for img and div.  As in img, div { margin:0px; padding:0px }